# Error in MySQL on create statement

Tags: mysql, ddl, mysql-error-150

I have a doubt what I'm doing wrong with the following table statement:

MySQL returns error 150

```
DROP table usuario;
DROP table MiTabla;

CREATE TABLE usuario(
id smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(20) not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

Insert into usuario (NAME) VALUES ('Antonio'),('Jose'),('Manuel');


CREATE TABLE MiTabla(
id smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (name) REFERENCES usuario (name)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: My Doubt comes in the foreign key statement

Comment: Did you do a search on Stackoverflow? There seem to be several posts about error 150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a foreign key relationship to just any column.  It needs to have an index.  The *easiest* method is:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario (
  id smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(20) not null unique
);
```

However, the *correct* method is to use primary keys for the relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla(
  id smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
  usuario_id smalling unsigned not null,
  foreign key (usuario_id) REFERENCES usuario(id)
);
```

Comment: so how can i check if have a vlue in column of another table do i add an index? and if is how it should be done?

Comment: @user2862454 . . . Use the primary key.  That is the right way to set up a foreign key relationship.